# Java: Sort Arraylist of objects on property

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a Array list of object for class `"Emp"[String eno, skill;   ArrayList<Jobs> Empjobs;]`.

EmpJobs in itself is an arraylist for class `"Jobs"[String jobId, skill;int priority, TTC;]`.

Now in code I created few object of Emps, say `Emp1, Emp2` and they have 2 jobs assigned to each as objects of Jobs class.

`job11,job12` assigned to **Emp1**

`job21, job22` assigned to **Emp2**

I need to sort Arraylist of Emp based on total of their jobs TTC(Time to Completeion). I tried using comparor method but no succeess. Any help will be much appreciated.below are snippets of code.

Also to add,

Emp array values are like : `'EmpId#Skill'`

Job Array values are like :  `'skill#priority#TTC#JobId'`

I am not able to work out `Collections.sort(emp2,new MyComparator());`

```
class EmpJobsAssign{
    class Emp
    {
    String eno, skill;
    ArrayList<Jobs> Empjobs;
    public Emp(){
        }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("eno:"+this.eno+
                " skill: "+ this.skill+
                " Job: "+  this.Empjobs);
        }
    }

public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Emp> {
@Override
public int compare(Emp e1, Emp e2) {
    if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC)
     {
         return 1;
     }
    else if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;    
} 
}

class Jobs
    {
    String jobId, skill;
    int priority, TTC;
    public Jobs(){
     }
     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("jobId:"+this.jobId+
                " skill: "+ this.skill +
                " priority: "+ this.priority +
                " TTC: "+ this.TTC);
        }
     }

public static void main(String []args){

        String[] arrayEmp = {"w4#j","w1#c","w2#c","W3#j"}; 
        String[] arrayJob = {"c#3#25#obj1","j#2#20#obj2","j#1#45#obj3","c#4#45#obj4","c#1#15#obj5"}; 
        EmpJobsAssign HW =new EmpJobsAssign();
        EmpJobsAssign.Emp emp=HW.new Emp();
        EmpJobsAssign.Jobs job=HW.new Jobs(); 
        Emp[] emps= HW.SortEmp(arrayEmp,0);
        Jobs[] empjobs=HW.SortJob(arrayJob,1,2);
        int jobindex=0;
        while(jobindex < empjobs.length)
        {
         job=empjobs[jobindex];
            ArrayList<Emp> emp2=new ArrayList<Emp>(); 
             String AssignedFlag="";
            for(int empindex=0;empindex<emps.length;empindex++)
            {
                AssignedFlag="F";
                emp=emps[empindex];
               if(emp.Empjobs == null) {emp.Empjobs=new ArrayList<Jobs>();}
                if(emp.skill.equals(job.skill) && emp.Empjobs.isEmpty()){
                    emp.Empjobs.add(job);
                    System.out.println("empjobs : " +emp);  
                    AssignedFlag="T";
                    System.out.println("Emp2  "+ emp2.size());
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" AssignedFlag "+AssignedFlag);
            if(AssignedFlag.equals("F")) {
                Collections.sort(emp2,new MyComparator());
                 System.out.println("Inside If  "+ emp2.get(0));
                Iterator itr=emp2.iterator(); 
                while(itr.hasNext()){
                    System.out.println("test "+ itr.next());
                }
            }
            jobindex++;
        }
        System.out.println("check");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(emps));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(empjobs)); 
 }

private Emp[] SortEmp(String[] a, int index1)
    {
        Emp[] SortEmp=new Emp[a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(a[i].substring(1,2))>Integer.parseInt(a[j].substring(1,2))){
                    String temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
                }
                Emp tempEmp = new Emp();
                tempEmp.eno=a[i].split("#")[0];
                tempEmp.skill=a[i].split("#")[1];
            SortEmp[i]=tempEmp;
        }
        return SortEmp;
    }

    private Jobs[] SortJob(String[] a, int index1, int index2)
    {
        Jobs[] SortJobs=new Jobs[a.length];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++){
                if(Integer.parseInt(a[i].split("#")[index1])>Integer.parseInt(a[j].split("#")[index1])){
                    String temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
                 if(Integer.parseInt(a[i].split("#")[index1])==Integer.parseInt(a[j].split("#")[index1])){
                    if(Integer.parseInt(a[i].split("#")[index2]) > Integer.parseInt(a[j].split("#")[index2])){
                    String temp=a[i];
                    a[i]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
                }
                Jobs tempJobs=new Jobs();
                tempJobs.jobId=a[i].split("#")[3];
                tempJobs.skill=a[i].split("#")[0];
                tempJobs.priority=Integer.parseInt(a[i].split("#")[1]);
                tempJobs.TTC=Integer.parseInt(a[i].split("#")[2]);
            SortJobs[i]=tempJobs;
        }
        return SortJobs;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Your names are sorry, bizarre. Variables go camelCase (always). Also: dont abbreviate, especially on class names (like `Emp` - plain horrible).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ghostcat. Well this is my first professional java code. I will work on your feedbacks.

Comment: Don'T get me wrong, but this code is about a zillion miles away from "professional". I hope you simply mean that this is like your first "real" attempt to solve an assignment with java.

Comment: Unrelated two: you want us to spend our time to help you solve your problem. So you please: A) put up code that compiles (when it doesnt compile, give exact error messages) B) put up code that is correctly indented and formatted. Thing is: your code is just 10 times harder to read then it ought to be.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put down your own comparison if you don't have to.

Your compare() boils down to:

```
return Integer.compare(e1.Empjobs.TTC, e2.Empjobs.TTC);
```

Completely eliminating the chance of introducing such subtle typos as your original code is showing (where you simply did a < b, a  b).

Comment: Below error is seen on compilaton:                               
HelloWorld.java:23: error: cannot find symbol    if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC)                                                                                                                                                                   
 symbol:   variable TTC

Comment: I just **copied** your code here. I am telling you: you don't need to compare yourself, when you have **two** int values, you can use Integer.compare(a, b) to compare them. When you now find that *your* own code `e1.empjobs.TTC` is invalid ... well. That is *your* code.

Answer (score 2):

The comparator is incorrectly implemented, both *if* statements have the same predicate.

```
@Override
public int compare(Emp e1, Emp e2) {
    if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC)      // predicate 1
     {
         return 1;
     }
    else if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC) // predicate 2, same as predicate 1
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

Change the second predicate to `e1.Empjobs.TTC < e2.Empjobs.TTC`.

Comment: Below error is seen on compilaton:                               
HelloWorld.java:23: error: cannot find symbol    if (e1.Empjobs.TTC > e2.Empjobs.TTC)                                                                                                                                                                   
 symbol:   variable TTC